# Filling in missing data in Pandas using KNNImputer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, knn

I have a dataframe with attributes of different cities. I am trying to fill in the missing data using KNNImputer. I am having trouble picking a value of K. So, for each value of K I tried using KNNImputer to fit and transform the original dataframe. Then I deleted random records from the complete dataframe and used the original imputer to fill in new missing values. I then computed the difference between the original filled dataframe and the randomly filled dataframe to find the error, assuming that iI would pick the value of K with the least error.

```
error=[]
for s in strategies:
    imputer =  KNNImputer(n_neighbors=int(s))
    transformed_df = pd.DataFrame(imputer.fit_transform(X))
    dropped_rows, dropped_cols = np.random.choice(ma_water_numeric.shape[0], 10, replace=False), np.random.choice(ma_water_numeric.shape[1], 10, replace=False)
    compare_df = transformed_df.copy()
    for i in np.arange(10):
        compare_df.iat[dropped_rows[i], dropped_cols[i]]=np.nan
    compare_df = imputer.transform(compare_df)
    error.append(sum(abs(compare_df-transformed_df)))
```

I am now getting the same error for all the values of K.
Is there a better way of doing this or an in-built way to check the appropriate value of K?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## Why the same error throughout iterations ?

The reason you have the same error at every iteration is because you are not calling the correct `sum` method.

```
for n_rows in range(100):
    range_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 15, (10,n_rows)))
    range_df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 15, (10,n_rows))
    assert sum(abs(range_df-range_df2)) == sum(range(n_rows))
# > No AssertionError
```

What you are doing is sum the indices, which are in this instance a range of integers from 0 to n_rows. If you get `66` for all errors, then your DataFrame obviously has 12 rows:

```
sum(range(12))
# > 66
```

To get the desired error, you can replace your last line by :

```
error.append(abs(compare_df-transformed_df).sum().sum())
```

## Apart from this, is there something wrong ?

### 1. Objects of comparison

You are comparing two predictions together, instead of comparing predictions with ground truth.

The "dumber" your imputer is, the more likely it is to make the same predictions.

Let's say it always predicts the same value, which is the dumbest a model can get. Its predicted values, not taking the invariant values into account, would be 100% accurate among each other.

We must compare predictions against expected values to be able to judge its accuracy, which is what we often want.

You would typically split your training data in two (not necessarily with the same length) : one split for the fitting and one split for the validation.

### 2. Randomization is inside the loop

Randomization is... well, random. You cannot say consistently if a model is better than another if the data on which we compare them keep changing.

You should do the "nan values filling" outside of the training loop.

### 3. Using DataFrames instead of numpy arrays

Usually, we use the most convenient form then format it, when needed.

In fact, if you had used numpy arrays inside the iterations, you would not have gotten the error mentioned in the first part of this answer.

## Any better way of doing it ?

### Some context

What you are intending is called hyperparameter tuning. There are several strategies to do this, from which we make our choice relative to the total process time. [Here are some of those strategies](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#hyper-parameter-optimizers). One can also make their own strategy if it doesn't exist in an implemented form, to fit specific needs, but they will still find in scikit_learn convenient classes to help them.

Since your data volume is not huge, we can try all combinations within some range.

### Let's recap

1. We want to have ground truth data to compare all predictions with.
2. We want to split so we can measure the true accuracy of the models. I will assume that your dataframe is the available data for the whole training process.
3. We want accurate ways to measure the accuracy and compare them.

### Let's practice

#### Imports

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, ParameterGrid
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer
```

#### The data preparation

We will make use of the all-powerful [train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html).
Our complete dataset is the `y_true` (ground_truth). The dataset filled with nans is our X. We will split both of in two: one split `X_train` for the training (with y_train as ground truth values), one split `X_val` for the validation (with y_val as ground truth values).

```
# ma_water_numeric is our complete validation dataframe.
# X_copy will be our training data.
# Let's use numpy arrays.
X = ma_water_numeric.values

# Now we fill with nans with your method, but outside the loop.
dropped_rows = np.random.choice(X.shape[0], 10, replace=False)
dropped_cols = np.random.choice(X.shape[1], 10, replace=False)
for r, c in zip(dropped_rows, dropped_cols):
    X[r, c]=np.nan

# We split: 20% spare for the validation, 80% for the learning part,
# with a constant random state to make it reproducible.
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, ma_water_numeric.values, test_size=0.2, random_state=117)
```

#### The grid search

The usual way to find the best combination of parameter is to use [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html).
Unfortunately, as far as I know, there is no straightforward way to use it with models that don't have a "predict" method. (It is not impossible though, but it requires more in-depth object-oriented designs that you can find online if you are interested.)

Instead of that, we can use the convenient class [ParameterGrid](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ParameterGrid.html#sklearn.model_selection.ParameterGrid) to create every combination of parameters. To better see its practicality, I added another parameter to optimize: `weights`. (See the [KNNImputer documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.KNNImputer.html))

```
# Designing the parameters grid
param_grid = ParameterGrid({"n_neighbors": list(range(1, 15)),
     "weights": ["uniform", "distance"]})
# > [{'n_neighbors': 1, 'weights': 'uniform'}, {'n_neighbors': 1, 'weights': 'distance'}, 
#    {'n_neighbors': 2, 'weights': 'uniform'}, {'n_neighbors': 2, 'weights': 'distance'}, 
# and so on ...]
```

#### The scoring

Nothing too fancy here. We will keep your (fixed) operation which may very much be called "Absolute error sum".

```
# Our custom scoring, as a function.
# Here a lambda function, because it is a quite simple one.
aes = lambda y_true, y_pred: np.abs(y_true-y_pred).sum().sum()
```

#### The training

Finally, we can do it in a loop. It is basically how sklearn's Grid Search works, except that it uses cross-validation instead of a single train-test-split.

```
# Let's train our models.
# We will keep the parameter and score of every combination.
results = []
for param_combination in param_grid:
    imputer = KNNImputer(**param_combination)
    train_pred = imputer.fit_transform(X_train)
    score = aes(y_train, train_pred)
    param_combination["train_score"]= score
    param_combination["val_score"] = aes(y_val, imputer.transform(X_val))
    results.append(param_combination)

print(results)
# > [{'n_neighbors': 1, 'weights': 'uniform', 'train_score': 41.0, 'val_score': 13.0},
#    {'n_neighbors': 1, 'weights': 'distance', 'train_score': 41.0, 'val_score': 13.0},
#    {'n_neighbors': 2, 'weights': 'uniform', 'train_score': 24.0, 'val_score': 18.0},
#    {'n_neighbors': 2, 'weights': 'distance', 'train_score': 24.682170521568423, 'val_score': 17.91644578836907},
#    and so on ...]
```

We stored the results as a list of dict so we can easily get them as a pandas DataFrame.

```
results_df = pd.DataFrame(results)
results_df
# > n_neighbors     weights     train_score     val_score
# 0     1           uniform     32.000000       16.000000
# 1     1           distance    32.000000       16.000000
# 2     2           uniform     40.000000       16.500000
# 3     2           distance    39.451212       15.841781
# and so on ...

results_df.sort_values("val_score")
# > n_neighbors     weights     train_score     val_score
# 10    6           uniform     36.000000       8.666667
# 11    6           distance    35.024333       8.986608
# 24    13          uniform     32.000000       9.111111
# 22    12          uniform     32.000000       9.111111
# and so on ...
```

We're done now. We know the best optimal set of parameters, but let's keep in mind that the result may vary a lot across different draws.

## Going further

### Avoiding overtfitting

[`Cross validation`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) is a way to make sure the model's performance is not constrained to peculiar training data. Such phenomenon is known as [overfitting](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_underfitting_overfitting.html).
It is much the case with models like KNN, which often tend to overfit with lower values of k.

### Getting the best estimator

We could have kept in memory the best estimator so far, inside the training loop.

```
results = []
best_estimator, best_params, best_val_score = None, None, np.inf
for param_combination in param_grid:
    imputer = KNNImputer(**param_combination)
    train_pred = imputer.fit_transform(X_train)
    score = aes(y_train, train_pred)
    val_score = aes(y_val, imputer.transform(X_val))
    param_combination["train_score"]= score
    param_combination["val_score"] = val_score
    results.append(param_combination)
    if val_score < best_val_score:
       best_estimator = imputer
       best_params = param_combination
       best_val_score = val_score

# Now we can use directly the best estimator
print(best_params)
# > {'n_neighbors': 6,
#    'weights': 'uniform',
#    'train_score': 36.000000,
#    'val_score': 8.666667}
some_other_pred = best_estimator.transform(some_other_data)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the in depth answer! I guess the main problem I was running into is that I don't have a y_train or y_val to go off of- my original dataset has nans that I'm trying to fill in. Would it be valid to do this with the non-nan values and then use those parameters to fill in the original nans?

Comment: The issue is that every set of parameters would be correct in its own way. You can also choose the function to go with for each attribute. For example, to fill the "wage" column, you could group the cities by state then sort by population, then [interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html#pandas.DataFrame.interpolate) the nans. To fill the "mean temperature", it would be based on geolocalisation. Etc...